Dell BIOS Updates Script Freezes
I need to be able to update the BIOS on over 5,000 Dell computers when there is a critical BIOS update.  I've messed with batch files and Powershell.  This is the latest Powershell.  When I run it, it just hangs and doesn't do anything.  It doesn't create the logs I want so I don't know how it's hanging up.  Any help would be appreciated.
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -scope Process -Force

# Define installer path
$installerPath3460 = "\\OurUNCPath\Precision 3460\Precision_3260_3460_3.3.2.exe"
$installerPath5000 = "\\OurUNCPath\OptiPlex 5000\OptiPlex_5000_1.19.0.exe"

# Get computer model
$computerModel = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Model

# Check computer model and install corresponding update
switch ($computerModel) {
  "Precision 3460" {
    Start-Process $installerPath3460 -ArgumentList "/s /p=DUMMYPASSWORD l="C:\BIOSUpdate\240417.log" -Wait
    Write-Host "Installed BIOS update for Dell Precision 3460."
  }
  "Precision 5000" {
    Start-Process $installerPath5000 -ArgumentList "/s /p=DUMMYPASSWORD /l="C:\BIOSUpdate\240417.log" -Wait
    Write-Host "Installed BIOS update for Dell Optiplex 5000."
  }
  default {
    Write-Warning "This script is intended for Dell Precision 3460 or 5000. Model: $computerModel"
  }
}

# Check for errors (use ExitCode property)
if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
  Write-Error "Error: Installation failed. Exit code: $($process.ExitCode)"
}


I want it to get the model of the PC
Originally I wanted it to download and install the BIOS from Dell's website, but I will also take it from a UNC path.
I do not want a reboot
I would like a log file
It needs to put in the BIOS setup password
All Dell machines
All Win 11 23H2 machines


Have you tried running without Start-Process? & $installerPath3460 /s /p=DUMMYPASSWORD l="C:\BIOSUpdate\240417.log"

Windows update does this now.

removing the Start-Process line didn't work.  Windows Update hasn't been doing the BIOS well enough.  I want to manually control it.

How are you running it remotely?

I use SCCM right now.  I've ran it as a script and as a program.
